# How to retrive same name attributes of joined table in active record rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following association

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

comments and articles table both contains column name text. I want to join both the table and would like to to get all the attributes from articles table including text attribute and text attribute from comments table.
In sql i would do something like this

```
select comments.text as comment_text, articles.* from articles,comments
```

I want to achieve same o/p using active record query.
I tried following thing but it didn't work

```
Article.joins(:comments).select("articles.*", "comments.text as comment_text")
```

Above query only return text attribute of comment and not the text attribute of articles table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is how to do a eager loading.

```
Article.includes(:comments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Article.includes(:comments).select("articles.*, comments.text as comment_text")
```